# multiple p:fileUpload in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm having trouble trying to use `p:fileUpload` in `ui:repeat`. The user picks if he wants to upload a file OR he picks an entity in a `selectOneMenu`. Nor the getter or the setter of my array seem to be called.

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{adminCreateTeam.teamComposition}" varStatus="status">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{ (adminCreateTeam.memNew[status.index].booleanValue())}">
            <!-- create new user -->                            
             ...
            <!-- image associated with the user -->
            <p:fileUpload
                value="#{adminCreateTeam.memPics[status.index]}"
             fileLimit="1"
            mode="simple"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
 </ui:repeat>
```

I tried with an array and an arraylist for `memPics`, in both case the getters and setters of those weren't called. However when using ArrayList, if I don't put null values in it from the get go, I'll have an `indexOutOfBondException`. So I prepopulate it with null values. Which I don't understand since neither the setter nor the getter is called..

so mempics:

```
private List<UploadedFile> memPics;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    teamComposition = new User[5];
    memPics = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();
    memPics.add(null); 
    memPics.add(null);
    memPics.add(null);
    memPics.add(null);
    memPics.add(null);
}
```

Comment: How do you trigger an action for uploading files? `ajax` associated with command components triggering the action needs to be disabled for `<p:fileUpload>` with `mode="simple"` to work, if you accidentally forgot to do so.

Comment: @BalusC Could you expand "better wrap your model in a real model object rather than relying on loop index" please ? I found my code bad also but I didn't really have an answer for it. And sorry for not specifying my version, I thought PF 5.2 was the latest.

Comment: @Tiny thanks it works now, I usually use advanced mode that's why I didn't catch that. Please post it as answer so I can accept it. I 've got a bit of OCD when it comes to when questions are answered in comments. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax associated with command components triggering the action needs to be disabled for  with mode="simple" to work